# Unable to use multiple instances of spring event listener

Tags: java, spring, events, event-handling

I am trying to get familiar with the spring event listener in java and I am encountering weird behavior.
I have a publisher class and a listener class and I am trying to use multiple instances of the same listener class (don't know if it's possible).
Here is my code:

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        testEvents();
    }

    private static void testEvents() throws InterruptedException {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext eventPublisherContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(EventListenerConfig.class);
        CustomSpringEventPublisher eventPublisher = eventPublisherContext.getBean(CustomSpringEventPublisher.class);
        List<CustomSpringEventListener> listenersList = new ArrayList<CustomSpringEventListener>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            listenersList.add(i, new CustomSpringEventListener());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            LocalDateTime now  = LocalDateTime.now();
            eventPublisher.doStuffAndPublishAnEvent("new event " + now.format(Formats.isolong));
        }
    }
}
```

My listener class looks like that:

```
@Component
public class CustomSpringEventListener implements ApplicationListener<CustomSpringEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(CustomSpringEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Received spring custom event - " + event.getMessage());
    }

}
```

My publisher class looks like that:

```
@Component
public class CustomSpringEventPublisher {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    public void doStuffAndPublishAnEvent(final String message) {
        System.out.println("Publishing custom event --> " + message);
        this.applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new CustomSpringEvent(this, message));
    }

}
```

My config class looks like that:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"some.local.directory"})
public class EventListenerConfig {
}
```

I would expect the output of this code would be one print for the publish followed by 5 prints of the receiving. However, the actual output is:

```
Publishing custom event --> new event 2020-02-17T08:07:03.349
Received spring custom event - new event 2020-02-17T08:07:03.349
Publishing custom event --> new event 2020-02-17T08:07:08.389
Received spring custom event - new event 2020-02-17T08:07:08.389
Publishing custom event --> new event 2020-02-17T08:07:13.403
Received spring custom event - new event 2020-02-17T08:07:13.403
```

It seems like the `for` loop in which I add new instances of the same listener to a list is being ignored. Why is that happening? Is it even possible to make several instances of the same listener and have them receive the published event? How can I alter my code to make it work? What would happen if I will try to instantiate the same listener in several threads working together, would only one of them respond to the event?
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't. You are creating instances outside of the application context. Spring doesn't know anything about those event listeners so they won't be doing anything.

Comment: ok. so what should I do in order to make it work?

Comment: Register them as beans in the application context.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Register who? the event listener is already registered as a component, I just want to make several instances of it.

Comment: @Component adds a bean to the application context. When you use `.getBean(...)` you get this specific bean from the context. Thus at the moment you have one listener and one publisher in your context. If you want to add more listeners programmatically you can do this by means of `applicationContext.registerBean(...)` (or similar). However, I’d recommend you have a look on spring integration. There is probably all you need (e.g. the integration flow builder).

Comment: All the listeners need to be beans. There is just a single one registered as a bean (that is controlled by Spring) the others are just instances you created. Using `registerbean` won't work as event listeners are detected early in the process. So you would need to manually add it to the context or just create 6 beans of that type.

Comment: The thing is that I want to use the same listener (which is already registered) in several classes. The amount of those classes is unknown, I could use 3 or 30. So based on your answer I guess it's impossible? If I could make several instances of a class and use them independently, why can't I do the same with listeners?